# Filter dictionary in a simple and readable manner

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures

Using python3.4 I'm trying to filter a firewall rulebase exported as JSON and converted to a dictionary. I want to filter based on user defined criteria but I can't seem to be able to do that without difficult to read constructs with a lot of loops and if statements.

The dict from my firewall entries is quite large so I've shortened them a litte.

2 examples:

```
entry1 = {'action': 'accept',
          'dstintf': [{'name': 'ZN_HDW', 'q_origin_key': 'ZN_HDW'}],
          'srcintf': [{'name': 'ZN_AUDIT', 'q_origin_key': 'ZN_AUDIT'}]
         }
entry2 = {'action': 'accept',
          'dstintf': [{'name': 'ZN_HDW', 'q_origin_key': 'ZN_HDW'}],
          'srcintf': [{'name': 'ZN_DMZ', 'q_origin_key': 'ZN_DMZ'},
                      {'name': 'ZN_MGMT', 'q_origin_key': 'ZN_MGMT'},
                      {'name': 'ZN_AUDIT', 'q_origin_key': 'ZN_AUDIT'}]
         }
```

I wanted to create a data structure to compare against the 2 examples and created to following:

```
filter = {'action': 'accept',
          'srcintf': [{'name': 'ZN_AUDIT', 'q_origin_key': 'ZN_AUDIT'}]
         }
```

After some searching on how to compare these structures I ended up with some readable code. My problem is it doesn't evaluate to true on entry2 (which has multiple source interfaces):

```
>>> filter.items() <= entry1.items()
True
>>> filter.items() <= entry2.items()
False
```

Any tips on how I should do this?

EDIT:
Using the answer Eric Duminil below I'm able to create something (see below), although it's still not as readable as I want it. Any further tips?

```
example = entry2
# Compare entry to filter
noMatch = 0
for key in filter:
    if isinstance(example[key], list):
        # Convert list of dicts to list for easier comparing
        tmpExample = [d['name'] for d in example[key]]
        # Break if entry does not contain all criteria
        if not all(value in tmpExample for value in filter[key]):
            noMatch = 1
            print("No match on: " + str(filter[key]))
            break
    elif filter[key] != example[key]:
        # Simple string comparing
        noMatch = 1
        print("No match on: " + str(filter[key]))
        break

if noMatch == 0:
    print("Match")
else:
    print(" No match")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Theory

The data structure inside `'dstintf'` and `'srcintf'` doesn't make this problem easier. A list of dicts is almost never the correct type.

Depending on your needs, you should probably convert it to a dict:

```
>>> data = [{'name': 'ZN_DMZ', 'q_origin_key': 'ZN_DMZ'},
...                       {'name': 'ZN_MGMT', 'q_origin_key': 'ZN_MGMT'},
...                       {'name': 'ZN_AUDIT', 'q_origin_key': 'ZN_AUDIT'}]
>>> {d['q_origin_key']:d['name'] for d in data}
{'ZN_AUDIT': 'ZN_AUDIT', 'ZN_MGMT': 'ZN_MGMT', 'ZN_DMZ': 'ZN_DMZ'}
```

But if the values for both `name` and `q_origin_key` are always equal, you could just use a list or a set:

```
>>> [d['name'] for d in data]
['ZN_DMZ', 'ZN_MGMT', 'ZN_AUDIT']
>>> {d['name'] for d in data}
set(['ZN_AUDIT', 'ZN_MGMT', 'ZN_DMZ'])
```

It should be easier to filter your data now, without loop or `if`s.

Finally, `dict.items()` returns a list of tuples in an arbitrary order.

I don't think `dict1.items() <= dict2.items()` will help you for anything.

## Example

It might be a good idea to split your code into multiple functions and work with sets:

```
query = {'action': 'accept',
         'srcintf': [{'name': 'ZN_AUDIT', 'q_origin_key': 'ZN_AUDIT'}]
         }

entry1 = {'action': 'accept',
          'dstintf': [{'name': 'ZN_HDW', 'q_origin_key': 'ZN_HDW'}],
          'srcintf': [{'name': 'ZN_AUDIT', 'q_origin_key': 'ZN_AUDIT'}]
          }

entry2 = {'action': 'accept',
          'dstintf': [{'name': 'ZN_HDW', 'q_origin_key': 'ZN_HDW'}],
          'srcintf': [{'name': 'ZN_DMZ', 'q_origin_key': 'ZN_DMZ'},
                      {'name': 'ZN_MGMT', 'q_origin_key': 'ZN_MGMT'},
                      {'name': 'ZN_AUDIT', 'q_origin_key': 'ZN_AUDIT'}]
          }


def compare_values(value1, value2):
    if isinstance(value1, list) and isinstance(value2, list):
        return set(d['name'] for d in value1).issubset(set(d['name'] for d in value2))
    else:
        return value1 == value2

def is_a_match(query, entry):
    do_not_match = [key for key in query if not compare_values(
        query[key], entry.get(key))]
    for key in do_not_match:
        print("%r does not match" % key)
    return len(do_not_match) == 0

print(is_a_match(query, entry1))
# True
print(is_a_match(query, entry2))
# True
print(is_a_match({'action': 'decline'}, entry2))
# 'action' does not match
# False
```

Comment: Thanks for the help so far but my result still isn't very readable (see edit). Any further tips?